# How to encode a image saved in memory to Base64 in Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x

I already have the image saved in memory but I need to encode the image in base64.
The intent is store the encode in a Pandas DataFrame because this code is inside a python script that will run inside SQL Server.
I only need the encoding step. Everything else is working really well.

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buf, format='png')
buf.seek(0)
im = Image.open(buf)

with open(im, "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

total_description['cartaX'] = 'data:image/png;base64,' + str(encoded_string) 

buf.close()
```

This is only the code for saving the plot in a image format in memory and trying to encode the image.

When I have the image saved I can encode, but when I store in memory I get an error.
How can I do it? Save the image it's not a option because this is running in the database

**Actual status**
I already can save de image in memory and encode de image in base64 in the VS code. But in the SQL server do not run.
This is the code that I use and works on VS code

```
my_stringIObytes = io.BytesIO()                 # create file in memory
plt.savefig(my_stringIObytes, format='png')     # save file in memory 
my_stringIObytes.seek(0)                        # move to the beginning of file
my_base64_jpgData = base64.b64encode(my_stringIObytes.read())
total_description['cartaX'] = 'data:image/png;base64,' + str(my_base64_jpgData)
```

What would you suggest I change for this work in SQL Server?

Comment: How are you trying to save it in memory? The `fname` parameter accepts file-like objects such as, say, an instance of `io.BytesIO`.

Comment: with the plt.savefig 
I think its stored in memory

Comment: If you want to save it to SQL Server why do you want it as Base64?

Comment: Because it's easy to decode by a web app. 
This image is a graph that are the result of data manipulation and analysis. The company I work for want base64 because the app can read this format. It's their requirement not my choice.

Comment: Normally a client-facing API would take care of converting stored binary data to base64 format before transmitting it to the requesting clients. Be aware that base64 encoding increases the size of the data - since every 3 bytes gets converted to 4 characters you're adding a 33% storage penalty.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code snippet on internet:

```
import base64
 
def get_base64_encoded_image(image_path):
    with open(image_path, "rb") as img_file:
        return base64.b64encode(img_file.read()).decode('utf-8')
```

[click](https://www.techcoil.com/blog/how-to-use-python-3-to-convert-your-images-to-base64-encoding/) 
Hope these is helpful.

Comment: thank you but unfortunately does not work 
I think I will need to convert the image to bytes first

Comment: hmmm, it works for me. It's kinda strange. Are you trying it out-of-the-box first?